# Why is Google Apps Script Requesting 'Delete Permission' When No Delete Functionality Is Used?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am working on a Google Apps Script project in which I utilize the following code to send emails:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(mailRecipients, subject, body);
```

However, I've noticed that the application requests the following permissions:

"Read, compose, send, and permanently delete all your email from Gmail."

My concern is that I'm only using the send function and do not require the delete permission. Is there a method or workaround to prevent the application from requesting the delete permission while still being able to send emails using GmailApp.sendEmail()?

Certainly, here's a possible response to the question:

I tried reviewing the documentation and searching for any specific parameters or options within the GmailApp.sendEmail() method that would allow me to limit the permissions requested by my Google Apps Script project. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any built-in options to fine-tune the permissions on a per-function basis.

Ideally, I was expecting to find a way to request only the necessary permissions for sending emails and not the "permanently delete all your email from Gmail" permission, which is not relevant to my script's functionality. My aim is to ensure that the application requests the least amount of permissions necessary to maintain security and user trust. If there's a workaround or best practice to achieve this, I'd greatly appreciate any guidance on the matter.

Comment: You are not looking at four separate permissions here ... This is _one_ permission, that allows for a couple of different tasks to be performed regarding the user's emails. "Read, compose, send, and permanently delete" is just the verbal explanation, _which_ tasks the app will be able to perform, if the user grants the _one_, single permission that is behind this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
First I wanted to make another script that is working as a service to send the mails.
But there is a faster solution:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(mailRecipients, subject, body);
```

With the class MailApp instead off GmailApp, the App is just asking for permission to "Send email as you"

[Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)